# Change contacts ringtone in iOS from external app

Tags: iphone, ios9, xcode8

I am planning to develop iOS app to change user ringtone with selected ringtone from app. I have googled and found few posts that say Apple does not allow external app to modify user preferences.  I am wondering if there is a chance this can be done with latest ios using Contacts Api or any similar APIs or any changes to this apple guideline. Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. There's no public API for this.